# 111: Connection refused error Nginx Multisite Wordpress VPS

Tags: php, nginx, server

I've spent several hours going back and forth trying to figure out why I continue to receive a 502 Bad Gateway error when trying to access my domain.

I'm attempting to run a VPS with multiple Wordpress installs. Here's one example of a Nginx config file for one of my domains:

```
listen 9000;
root /var/www/sitemysite;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

client_max_body_size 100M;

location / {
try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php?\$args; 
}

location ~ \.php\$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
}
}
```

Here is the listen directive from my PHP file www.conf:

```
listen = /var/run/php/php-fpm.sock
```

I changed the listen directive in www.conf to simply php-fpm.sock because I could not find php7.4-fpm.sock in the /var/run/php/ folder.

However, I continue to get a 502 Bad Gateway error and the error log outputs:

```
2022/02/27 21:29:10 [error] 661037#661037: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ??.???.??.???, server: _, request: "GET /wp-install HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mysite.com"
```

I've also tried switching out the port on the server config file. I am restarting Nginx and PHP before I check the domain every time I make a change. I feel like I have 2 issues going on and I haven't figured out the right combo fix yet to get it to work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the FPM config:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; All relative paths in this configuration file are relative to PHP's install
; prefix (/usr). This prefix can be dynamically changed by using the
; '-p' argument from the command line.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Global Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[global]
; Pid file
; Note: the default prefix is /var
; Default Value: none
; Warning: if you change the value here, you need to modify systemd
; service PIDFile= setting to match the value here.
pid = /run/php/php7.4-fpm.pid

; Error log file
; If it's set to "syslog", log is sent to syslogd instead of being written
; into a local file.
; Note: the default prefix is /var
; Default Value: log/php-fpm.log
error_log = /var/log/php7.4-fpm.log

; syslog_facility is used to specify what type of program is logging the
; message. This lets syslogd specify that messages from different facilities
; will be handled differently.
; See syslog(3) for possible values (ex daemon equiv LOG_DAEMON)
; Default Value: daemon
;syslog.facility = daemon

; syslog_ident is prepended to every message. If you have multiple FPM
; instances running on the same server, you can change the default value
; which must suit common needs.
; Default Value: php-fpm
;syslog.ident = php-fpm

; Log level
; Possible Values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug
; Default Value: notice
;log_level = notice

; Log limit on number of characters in the single line (log entry). If the
; line is over the limit, it is wrapped on multiple lines. The limit is for
; all logged characters including message prefix and suffix if present. However
; the new line character does not count into it as it is present only when
; logging to a file descriptor. It means the new line character is not present
; when logging to syslog.
; Default Value: 1024
;log_limit = 4096

; Log buffering specifies if the log line is buffered which means that the
; line is written in a single write operation. If the value is false, then the
; data is written directly into the file descriptor. It is an experimental
; option that can potentionaly improve logging performance and memory usage
; for some heavy logging scenarios. This option is ignored if logging to syslog
; as it has to be always buffered.
; Default value: yes
;log_buffering = no

; If this number of child processes exit with SIGSEGV or SIGBUS within the time
; interval set by emergency_restart_interval then FPM will restart. A value
; of '0' means 'Off'.
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_threshold = 0

; Interval of time used by emergency_restart_interval to determine when
; a graceful restart will be initiated.  This can be useful to work around
; accidental corruptions in an accelerator's shared memory.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_interval = 0

; Time limit for child processes to wait for a reaction on signals from master.
; Available units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;process_control_timeout = 0

; The maximum number of processes FPM will fork. This has been designed to control
; the global number of processes when using dynamic PM within a lot of pools.
; Use it with caution.
; Note: A value of 0 indicates no limit
; Default Value: 0
; process.max = 128

; Specify the nice(2) priority to apply to the master process (only if set)
; The value can vary from -19 (highest priority) to 20 (lowest priority)
; Note: - It will only work if the FPM master process is launched as root
;       - The pool process will inherit the master process priority
;         unless specified otherwise
; Default Value: no set
; process.priority = -19

; Send FPM to background. Set to 'no' to keep FPM in foreground for debugging.
; Default Value: yes
;daemonize = yes

; Set open file descriptor rlimit for the master process.
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_files = 1024

; Set max core size rlimit for the master process.
; Possible Values: 'unlimited' or an integer greater or equal to 0
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_core = 0

; Specify the event mechanism FPM will use. The following is available:
; - select     (any POSIX os)
; - poll       (any POSIX os)
; - epoll      (linux >= 2.5.44)
; - kqueue     (FreeBSD >= 4.1, OpenBSD >= 2.9, NetBSD >= 2.0)
; - /dev/poll  (Solaris >= 7)
; - port       (Solaris >= 10)
; Default Value: not set (auto detection)
;events.mechanism = epoll

; When FPM is built with systemd integration, specify the interval,
; in seconds, between health report notification to systemd.
; Set to 0 to disable.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default value: 10
;systemd_interval = 10

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Pool Definitions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Multiple pools of child processes may be started with different listening
; ports and different management options.  The name of the pool will be
; used in logs and stats. There is no limitation on the number of pools which
; FPM can handle. Your system will tell you anyway :)

; Include one or more files. If glob(3) exists, it is used to include a bunch of
; files from a glob(3) pattern. This directive can be used everywhere in the
; file.
; Relative path can also be used. They will be prefixed by:
;  - the global prefix if it's been set (-p argument)
;  - /usr otherwise
include=/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

Comment: Why you connect through 9000 port if listening on 80 port?

Comment: "fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;" "listen = /var/run/php/php-fpm.sock"
You're missing a /var/

Comment: @Justinas I changed the listening port to 9000 in server config but still receiving errors.

Comment: @ZacharyCraig Okay added that in as well and modified original post to include this but still getting gateway error. Thanks

Comment: I'd make sure you're editing the right config and nothing else is overriding it, it's trying to connect to fpm over a tcp socket connection not a unix socket file, so that's a problem, try restarting both php-fpm and nginx

Comment: @ZacharyCraig I can only restart php if I use `systemctl restart php7.4-fpm` not if I use `systemctl restart php-fpm` from the command line. However I cannot find a php7.4-fpm.conf file in /etc/php/7.4/fpm instead I can only find php-fpm.conf there and this is why I used `php-fpm.sock` in www.conf and `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;` in my server config.

Comment: add your fpm config to the question too.

Comment: @ZacharyCraig Added that in, TY